# Test class isnot covering execute method

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch

Test class isnot covering execute method.After checking debug log.It shows user id value as null

```
 "Userid" shows null values
```

[image]

---

```
   global class s360_BatchLoginWarningEmailAlert implements Database.Batchable<sobject>{

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc){

    DateTime tStartDate=system.today().addDays(-8);
    DateTime tEndDate=system.today().addDays(-7);
    Map<Id,Profile> profileIds = new Map<id,profile>([SELECT Id,UserLicenseId FROM Profile where UserLicenseId  in (SELECT Id FROM UserLicense where name ='Customer Community Plus')]);
    System.debug('profileIDs-'+profileIds.Keyset());
    List<User> userIds = [SELECT Id  FROM User WHERE profileId in:profileIds.Keyset() AND IsActive=True AND LastLoginDate >=:tStartdate and LastLoginDate <:tEnddate];
    System.debug('userids-'+userIds);
    //string id1='005m0000002lxtD';
    String query = 'SELECT Id,Email,ContactId FROM User where Id IN :userIds and ContactId!=null';
    system.debug('##query##'+query);
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, LIST<sobject> InactiveUsers) {
    list<id> conID= new  list<id>();
    system.debug('inactive users--'+InactiveUsers);
    EmailTemplate emailTemplate = [select Id, Body  from EmailTemplate where DeveloperName ='X120_Days_Warning_Email'];
    for(Sobject user:InactiveUsers){


        User user2 = (User)user;
          conID.add(user2.ContactId);

        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        email.setToAddresses(new String[] {user2.Email});
        email.setSaveAsActivity(false);
        email.setTargetObjectId(user2.Id);
        email.setTemplateId(emailTemplate.Id);
        //email.setWhatId(user2.Id);
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email}); 


    }    

    //For all Inactive users update the Document Access checkbox to false
    list<contact> con=[Select id,Document_Access__c from contact where id In :conID ];
       List<contact> conList=new List<contact>();
    system.debug('contactlist--'+conList);
    for(Contact c:con){

       c.Document_Access__c=false;
      conList.add(c);  

    }   

     map<id,contact> conmap = new map<id,contact>();


    if(!conList.isEmpty()){
        conmap.putall(conList);
        if(conmap.size()>0){
            system.debug('contact count--'+conmap.size());
            update conmap.values();
        }
    }

}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {}
}
```

---

Test class:

```
  @isTest
 public class s360_BatchLoginWarningEmailAlert_Test {
public static testmethod void test(){
    Account ac=S360_TestDataFactory.createAccountRecords();
    contact c=S360_TestDataFactory.createContactRecords(ac.Id);

    /** create users **/
    User user = new User();
    user.ProfileID = [Select Id From Profile Where Name='Customer Community Plus User'].id;
    user.EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1';
    user.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';
    user.TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/New_York';
    user.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';
    user.FirstName = 'first';
    user.LastName = 'last';
    user.Username = 'test@appirio.com';   
    user.CommunityNickname = 'testUser123';
    user.Alias = 't1';
    user.Email = 'no@email.com';
    user.IsActive = true;
    user.ContactId = c.Id;
    insert user;


    Test.startTest();

    s360_BatchLoginWarningEmailAlert b=new s360_BatchLoginWarningEmailAlert();
    DataBase.executeBatch(b);
    Test.stopTest();
}}
```

Execute method isnot covering:

[image]

Can anyone correct me where I have gone wrong and suggest me the changes.

Comment: The problem probably comes from this where clause: `LastLoginDate >=:tStartdate and LastLoginDate <:tEnddate`. No user is probably returned.

Comment: yes you are right.userid is coming null. How can I fix it in test class?

Comment: Why I got down votes. Whats the wrong in the question.If I post anyquestion Ill get down vote first. I didnt get proper answer till now.but people are marking it as down votes.

Comment: You're right some people are a little too strict. This is probably because some people think you didn't search enough before posting. For example with some debugs to find out that there are no user returned.

Comment: @MartinLezer  thats fine. but from last weeks I lost a lot of points because of down votes. after some time they are realizing and remove the down votes

Comment: @AnnappaPH All I see from your recent activity is: Posting questions with little to no proper online research. You could've easily fixed/solved most of them if you do more research. This makes the people to believe that you relay on others rather than yourself. Don't get me wrong here, I'm trying to help you out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't fix your issue, but don't use the `global` access modifier unless you need it (you don't here).

You can easily make your date ranges writable from your test. I suggest making them `@TestVisible static` variables.

```
@TestVisible static Integer daysAgoMin = 7;
@TestVisible static Integer daysAgoMax = 8;

public void start(...)
{
    Date startDate = Date.today().addDays(-daysAgoMax);
    Date endDate = Date.today().addDays(-daysAgoMin);
... WHERE LastLoginDate >= :startdate and LastLoginDate < :endDate
```

From your test you can then make sure today is included.

```
MyBatch.daysAgoMin = -1;
MyBatch.daysAgoMax = 11;
```

---

Also check out **[How to Write Good Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests)** (emphasis mine):

> #### Verify the results are correct
>
> **Verifying that your code works as you expect it to work is the most important part of unit testing**. It’s also one of the things that Force.com developers commonly neglect. Unit tests that do not verify the results of the code aren’t true unit tests. They are commonly referred to as [smoke tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_testing#Smoke_testing_in_software_development), which **aren’t nearly as effective or informative as true unit tests**.
>
> A good way to tell if unit tests are properly verifying results is to look for liberal use of the `System.assert()` methods. If there aren’t any `System.assert()` method calls, then the tests aren’t verifying results properly. And, no, `System.assert(true);` doesn’t count.
>
> Sample verification code for this trigger might look like this:
>
> ```
> a = [SELECT Name, Most_Recently_Created_Opportunity_Name__c
>      FROM Account
>      WHERE Id = :a.Id];
>
> System.assertEquals('My Opportunity', a.Most_Recently_Created_Opportunity_Name__c);
> ```
>
> Notice that this unit testing code explicitly verifies that the trigger performed the action that we expected.